# Linker error for DOMXPathResult and DOMXPathExpression in Swift

Tags: swift, webkit

I'm trying to use DOMXPathResult/DOMXPathExpression in my Swift application but get for some reasons a linker error for both. Other classes from the WebKit framework compile/link nicely. Both XPath classes also link in an Obj-C application. It's only a problem in Swift. WebKit is imported and linked to.

The error message I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DOMXPathExpression", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo18DOMXPathExpression in PluginWorker.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I solve this linker error?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No solution. I gave up for now.

Comment: WebKit is sometimes a black hole. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed with XCode 7.1.1.